# How can I get the token in JSON format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger

[image]

I am getting the token but it is not in `json` format. I am using a plugin to put all the response in `json` format. And It is all working well for all the API's except the gettoken API

```
[HttpPost("gettoken")]
public IActionResult GetToken([FromBody]TokenRequest Input)
{


        var oUser=_userRepository.AuthenticateUser(Input.UserName,Input.Password);
        if (oUser!=null)
        {

            var claimsdata = new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, oUser.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, oUser.Role)

            };
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:SigningKey"]));
            int expiryInMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(_configuration["Jwt:ExpiryInMinutes"]);
            var signInCred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                                                issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                                                audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                                                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expiryInMinutes),
                                                claims: claimsdata,
                                                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                                            );
            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return Ok(tokenString);
        }   

         return BadRequest("wrong request");

    // return View();
}
```

Comment: What's the json format you are expecting?

Comment: So, you return string, don’t you? There is no field to make a JSON. You might want to return object instead something like ‘new { token = tokenString }’. But I would not recommend to return an anonymous object due to readability and so on (bad practice). Create a model, and return it inside of Ok call.

Comment: Try with `return Ok(token);`. I hope you're supposed to return `object` not the `string` of `object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would recommend to define a model which will describe your security token the best.
Let's say that would be:

```
class SecurityToken
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public long Expires { get; set; }
}
```

There you will store your token string in Token prop. And it's expiration date in Expires prop. Of course, these fields are not obligatory.

Then, create your controller. I prefer inheriting `ControllerBase` from .NET Core.

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class SecurityController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize([FromBody] AuthData credentials)
    {
        try
        {
            var tokenString = await ObtainToken(credentials, out long expires);
            return Ok(new SecurityToken() {
                Token = tokenString,
                Expires = expires
            });
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(400, "Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

Let me describe it a bit. On the route api/v1/security/authorize passing some 'abstract' credentials data, i.e. user name and password, it would be available to obtain token. Method `ObtainToken` is just a sample, not a real method. I supposed it to be async, so the controller's action returns `Task<T>`. I used an 'IActionResult' as the more general: we are allowed to return `OK(object)` or StatusCode, BadRequest, etc. (ControllerBase methods).

As well you can define something like:

```
public SecurityToken  Authorize([FromBody] AuthData credentials)
    {
        var tokenString = ObtainToken(credentials, out long expires);

        return new SecurityToken
        {
            Token = tokenString,
            Expires = expires
        };
    }
```

And it will do the trick!

The thing is that serialization to JSON is accomplished behind the scene and you do not need to do it yourself.

Talking about your code, I thing you can start with to basic things:

1. Create your model, which you will return as the result. Note: the
   return value must be an object if you want JSON object at your
   front-end.
2. Modify `return Ok(tokenString)` of your action to return your model.

Comment: @arsam Ok. I will correct myself in the answer providing some code.

Comment: @arsam, here we go. Hope that will help

Comment: And what's the value added with this method? A JWT token by itself already has an expiry date (`exp` field)

Comment: @Tseng, there would be no need to extract it. I’ve added it only to  show that it is possible. As I mentioned it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Json(tokenString)` instead of `Ok(tokenString)`

Answer (score 1):

What you have is already an valid JWT token. You need to decode (its just base64) it on the Client side (JavaScript). For validating it, you need a library which will verify the signature with the token to make sure it hasn't been tampered.

The JWT token consists of three parts, separated by a "." (which you can see in the screenshots already): The header, the payload and the signature.

See https://jwt.io for more information. It also contains a list of libraries supporting decoding and veryifing of JWT Tokens on the client side (JavaScript, C# and other languages).

Current examples are [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) and [@panva/jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@panva/jose) for JavaScript/NodeJs

P.S. even a simple `"Some string"` is valid json as is `null`.